# How to use text to column to separate currency symbol from amount? Trying to delimit properly to create two separate columns for each

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so when I try to delimit the two the amount integer value populates in the cell to the right but the currency symbol gets deleted from the initial cell to the left.

**Can anyone please help so that the amount stays in the initial column and the currency symbol populates to the right column?  If not possible to do by text to column wizard, is there any other ways?

Thanks a million for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't use the currency symbol as a delimiter because it will just remove it (think tabs | commas). Maybe split by spaces and then by delimiter?

Comment: Also if the cell has the currency symbol as part of the number format, you can't split it out (I don't think).

Comment: @pgSystemTester Hmm thanks for replying, if it cant be done this way, are there any other ways? it seems so simple

Comment: [this may be of interest](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-formula-which-returns-the-currency-from-the/c5771cc9-eeb0-4985-9a8f-3efbb5729a81)

Comment: Just use `left(text,1)` and `mid(text,2,len(text))`?

Comment: How to accomplish your goal depends critically on the nature of the data.  Is it a text string?  Or is it a numeric value formatted to display as a currency? Either way, you will NOT be able to it using TextToColumns.  You could do it with formulas, VBA or Power Query however.

Answer (score 0):

To get currency:

```
=LEFT(D1;1)
```

[image]

Copy the result and paste it as values

[image]

Then remove currency from original column with Replace

[image]

Then change format of original column to Number or General, because by now it should be text.

[image]